# YouTube iframe api and Ads on Chromecast

Tags: youtube-api, chromecast

Two problems

1. Pre-roll ads are now being inserted but on Chromecast there's no way to skip. Is there an api call so that the user can be presented with a skip button to avoid them being forced to sit through long ads?
2. Sometimes the player just spins transitioning between the pre-roll ad and the actual video requested - just stays there. Can load another video though. Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: We are seeing this problem as well and its causing a lot of complaints from our users. Would love to see an API call to deal with skipping long ads after a few seconds.

Comment: Anyone from the YouTube team care to chip in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6310

It's resolved by showing only short, non-skippable ads for now, and will show longer ads only where the device has easy controls to skip.